# What is the best way to use pagination in android?

Tags: android, web-services, pagination

I am working on **social networking** project in which I am calling the
`api` and getting all the data in one time that makes some time to load
the class. So I am trying to create `Pagination`.I am not handling the
back-end. Another team of PHP is taking care of API's  So, My question
is, what would be the best if I create `Pagination` on `API` side or android
application side???

Comment: This is not about where you implement paging. Off course you need to implement it on both side (server and client). Lets say you have 100 rows in db and now you call an API which sends back 20 rows each time. In you listview or something you need to refresh the adapter on reaching the listview end or some other strategy. So its on both  Client and Server side

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain:- Thank you so much. how can I get 20 rows of  new data. How can I be sure that every time I am hitting the api, getting new data from it??? do I need to create some kind of indexing for this???

Comment: this can be done using `Limit` query and extra param you send to them about how many rows you received till now. By using that they send you the rows excluding the already received